# Limit what posts the community user can bump

Tags: feature-request, meta, community-user, bump

Quite a list of questions has been bumped on Meta, in the last hour:

- [But not in [Browsername here] SEDE Query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366902)
- [Cancel upvotes on older comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336772)
- [Does the "timeline" parameter work correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321554)
- [How to re-visit a topic that has been addressed years ago?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371020)
- [How "deep" should question tags go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302911)
- [Let the [flame]s burn?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358299)
- [Permalink button on bottom of Questions page appears to be broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314571)
- [Don't the numbers tell us a temporary tweak to the number of close vote reviews per person/day is in order?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294375)
- [Could we get a better way to see my favorite tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316337)
- [Tag synonym [tvOS] and [apple-tvos]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308726)

There's even a question that was bumped *yesterday*, still on the frontpage:

- [Will I lose reputation from an accepted answer if I mark it Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316366)

Most of these questions are no longer relevant, don't require attention, or are even [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The purpose of these bumps is as follows:

> The Community user randomly bumps old, unanswered questions to bring them to the attention of users and [maybe] get them answered. Note that in these circumstances, "unanswered" means that the question has no upvoted answers on it.
>   ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285978/community-modified-posts-appearing-on-homepage))

The thing is, every one of these questions *is* answered. The answer just didn't get any votes. That doesn't make the answer less valuable or correct.

These bumps bring noise to the frontpage, for (in my opinion) no gain.

---

I'd like to suggest a few changes to this bumping mechanism:

- Don't bump questions that have an answer that isn't scored negatively.
- Don't bump questions that are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
- Don't bump questions that are over 2 years old. (Timespan is debatable)

This way, the questions that *do* get bumped are more likely to actually require a answer or other attention.

Comment: Upvote the answers?

Comment: @JonasWilms: That doesn't fix the "problem", though. Sure, those specific questions don't get bumped again, but others will. Besides, I don't want to vote on an answer because a bot tells me the answer needs votes.

Comment: Heh! There is at least one question I answered and I didn't get an upvote. I need the meta rep. This is fine.

Comment: @rene: What about [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: can be reviewed, voted on, closed as well?

Comment: But does it _need_ more attention if it’s completed? That’s the point of those bumps...

Comment: We can only tell if someone revisits them. Can't rule out up front that all status-completed posts don't need attention.

Comment: I think we can. If it requires more attention, it's not "completed", and shouldn't have that tag, imo.

Comment: The problem is that many of these questions being bumped aren't relevant any more, and suppress active discussions and new questions. 10 of the posts on the front page, and increasing, are going to make it harder to find relevant discussions

Comment: One that was bumped [just now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308726) is interesting. A user already upvoted the answer on there after it being bumped ___7___ times, but that user (and with that, the vote) was deleted, resulting in it getting bumped again...

Comment: @Cerbrus If the user is still listed with UserID in comments, etc. (instead of disappearing), will the vote really be removed?

Comment: It’s a bit of an assumption, but seeing as the answer had no votes...

Answer (score 5):

Do we even need to bump *anything* on meta automatically?

I guess this feature exists to make sure more "bland" questions like burninate requests don't fall through the cracks and get exposed to more users. But unless we can make sure the bot has a high chance to hit "correct" targets this could result in an averse effect where questions get overlooked due to too much noise. Let's try to do a rough classification of the different cases we have for questions, and which of these would need a bot-bump:

- Posts which are still actively discussed are usually bumped naturally due to edits or new answers, so these are right out.
- Posts which are not actively discussed, which have reached a resolution or where everybody involved has moved on, don't need further discussion and thus shouldn't be bumped. This is basically the list in the OP - old posts, completed/declined/answered posts etc.
- Then we have posts which have no resolution, are not actively discussed, and *where OP (or someone else) is still interested in a resolution*. Let's call this **Category A**.
- the remainder are posts which have no resolution, are not actively discussed, and *where nobody is actively looking for a resolution*. This would be **Category B**.

For category A, if the original post is old it might warrant either creating a new post, or editing the post to reflect changes or describe why it is still relevant, so these could be actively bumped. If the post is somewhat recent (but old enough that it could be bumped), then we are in the territory of letting it be auto-bumped. But then again, it is somewhat recent and has at least one user interested in getting a resolution, so *why not let the user bump it instead of trying to automate this*? The interested user could simply do a trivial edit to bump the post, of course subject to some guidelines that describe when/how it is acceptable to bump something, and the usual guards against abuse (*).

For category B, these are the posts which truly slipped through the cracks. Somebody once wrote the question, it has no resolution, but everybody involved moved on. In some cases, this might simply be because the question is not useful to anybody anymore - e.g. a non-reproductible bug report. In other cases, this might be more valuable things like a burninate request which the OP forgot about (or moved on for other reasons). These questions *could* benefit from a bot-bump... but is this neccessary? If the problem under discussion still exists, chances are some other user will create a post about it sooner or later. And if nobody does, then how important can it really be?

**TL;DR**: In most cases, bumping a post that needs a bump could simply be done by the users. Where that is not possible because there is no active user interested in the post, the question becomes if it's worth the hassle to bump the post at all. Given that an automatic process will always have false positives and bump at least some useless stuff, I believe simply turning off the autobumps would not make meta a worse place.

---

(*) If someone is worried about creating trivial edits for the sake of bumping posts, well, we already have a lot of trivial edits because some users simply like to edit posts. I'm not going to name names but meta so far did not see the need to stop some users from bumping old, resolved posts by making extremely trivial edits (e.g. changing the capitalization or spacing of the term "Stack Overflow" without any other changes, changing two words in a single sentence that was already perfectly understandable, or slightly improving tags on old localized questions). Thus I don't see why we should be against trivial edits for the sake of bumping a post that still needs a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed but for the:

> Don't bump questions that have an answer that isn't scored negatively.

The un-answered is define with no acceptable or up-voted answer for a reason. If question has zero score answer then it define as un-answered as the answer can be nonsense.

In the main site I go over the "unanswered" queue and upvote those kind for the reason of have them consider "answered".

We should do the same in Meta.

Except that - I fully agreed.

Comment: Answers should not get upvotes just so that the question is considered answered

Comment: I didn't meant just up vote with no reason - if the answer is not good then don't up vote it - keep it as it is and then it should be bumped as the post has not good answer. Sometimes, good answer doesn't get up vote and then the bump is annoying - in that case, I upvote the answer so it won't bumped again

Comment: i mean... not all "good" answers need upvotes either.